# How to turn 蓬 into feminine given name?

Tags: names, suffixes

I looked up a few points concerning feminine given names that might help, such as different suffixes like -e, -ka, -ko, etc. but am at a loss as to how to fit them together ("Yomogiko"?) and also how to write this in kana.

Comment: You can check [here](http://jisho.org/search/%23names%20%E8%93%AC) for ideas. Note that most names with 蓬 are surnames. I think it would be interesting to ask about more general principles to use kanji with altered readings in names. (As in, would 蓬美花 ほみか be a valid name?)

Comment: Could you [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and give us the background context about why you want such a specific piece of information? Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that there is a LOT of variance in naming conventions from generation to generation and family to family.  Look up "kira kira" names to see just how far out there actual given names get on a semi-regular basis.  Even if you ask for a "conventional" name, you'd have to give more details on what "level" of conventional, if that makes sense.

Comment: You can also have a look here http://name.m3q.jp/list?g=&s=%E8%93%AC

Comment: (蓬(Yomogi) already sounds like one to me...) When it comes to naming I don't think there are strict rules prescribing which suffixes must (if at all) be added to which base-words. It's more art than grammar, which is not to say there aren't any conventions. Sound is also important. It takes a sufficiently developed ear for the music of Japanese names to be able to judge whether a given given name has a natural (or conventional) ring.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we have many common female given names which follow the `kanji representing a plant name + 子(ko)` pattern:

- 菊子 (*Kikuko*, 'chrysanth' + 子)
- 百合子 (*Yuriko*, 'lily' + 子)
- 松子 (*Matsuko*, 'pine' + 子)

蓬子 is less common compared to the names above, but it's a possible female given name. It's usually read as ほうこ (*Hōko*) rather than よもぎこ (*Yomogiko*). The [on-yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#On.27yomi_.28Sino-Japanese_reading.29) of the kanji 蓬 is ほう (*hō*), and we usually don't prefer long readings (more than 2 [morae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_(Japanese_prosody))) before *ko* for whatever reason. In addition, some people may feel 蓬 (read as *hō*) is a "fortunate" kanji related to [this legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Penglai).

`-e` and `-ka` both appear in many female given names, and both have several possible kanji. But I don't know how to form a natural-sounding person name using 蓬 and `-e/-ka`. Don't ask me why.